# YouTube Upload Failure, possibly uploads too fast

Tags: java, youtube-api, batch-processing, youtube-data-api

I have a Java batch process which scans a directory and automatically uploads videos to YouTube using the v3 API.  The jobs processes a few hundred videos a day.  Of those uploaded 20-50% result in the grey ellipse icon and eventually the error "Failed (unable to convert video file)".

The videos are all mp4 format.  The videos all utilize the same API process which I will outline below.  The videos range between ~70MB & 150MB.

The process:
Authorize for Upload "https://www(dot)googleapis(dot)com/auth/youtube.upload", Set privacy to public, Set Snippet (Set channel, Set Title, Set Description, Set Tags)

```
        InputStream buffInStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        AbstractInputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent(MarketingConstants.YT_VIDEO_FORMAT, buffInStream);
        YouTube.Videos.Insert videoInsert = youtube.videos().insert("snippet,statistics,status", videoMetadata, mediaContent);
        videoInsert.setNotifySubscribers(false);
        MediaHttpUploader uploader = videoInsert.getMediaHttpUploader();
        // Set direct upload to TRUE and the job is remarkably efficient 2500kb/second (FAST)
        // Set to False, and the job is horribly inefficient 70kb/second (SLOW)
        uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(true);

        Video returnedVideo = videoInsert.execute();
```

Upon successful completion, update video data:

Authorize for Update "https://www(dot)googleapis(dot)com/auth/youtube", Get previously uploaded Video Id, Get snippet for said Video Id, Replace description with updated one (the job creates a tagged url for the description that incorporates the video id, hence the reason to update).

```
    snippet.setDescription(newDescription);

    // Update the video resource by calling the videos.update() method
    YouTube.Videos.Update updateVideosRequest = youtube.videos().update("snippet,status", video);

    Video videoResponse = updateVideosRequest.execute();
```

Finally, the process adds the video to a specific playlist within the original Channel based on content specifics.  To do this, it will Authorize for playlist update "https://www(dot)googleapis(dot)com/auth/youtube", find associated playlist id based on category (these are properties within the process), and update.

```
                ResourceId resourceId = new ResourceId();
            // Identifies this as a video, required for adding to playlist
            resourceId.setKind("youtube#video");
            resourceId.setVideoId(videoId);

            PlaylistItemSnippet playlistItemSnippet = new PlaylistItemSnippet();
            playlistItemSnippet.setPlaylistId(playlistId);
            playlistItemSnippet.setResourceId(resourceId);

            PlaylistItem playlistItem = new PlaylistItem();
            playlistItem.setSnippet(playlistItemSnippet);

            //Add to the playlist
            YouTube.PlaylistItems.Insert playlistItemsInsert = youtube.playlistItems().insert("snippet,contentDetails", playlistItem);

            PlaylistItem returnedPlaylistItem = playlistItemsInsert.execute();
```

The only difference I can see with the uploaded videos that fail versus succeed is in the logging.

For a successful upload:
2015-11-22 09:18:35:694|YouTubeMediaService.uploadFileToYouTube()|Upload in progress
2015-11-22 09:19:27:158|YouTubeMediaService.uploadFileToYouTube()|Upload Completed!
That was ~52 seconds.

For a failure upload:
2015-11-22 07:31:12:182|YouTubeMediaService.uploadFileToYouTube()|Upload in progress
2015-11-22 07:31:43:847|YouTubeMediaService.uploadFileToYouTube()|Upload Completed!
That was ~32 seconds.

It appears that the faster it uploads (closer to 30 seconds), the more likely it is to fail.  I do see some that take longer and still fail, but this is the only anomaly I've discovered.
Originally the process would set the privacy to private, then only set to public after successfully updating the information, but Google suggested we remove that due to a known glitch that can occur with switching the privacy settings.

So here's my question:
What do you suggest I do to mitigate this issue and ultimately achieve a successful upload rate closer to 95% or higher?
Should I remove the privacy portion all together?  Should I retry videos that upload too fast, e.g. remove the recently uploaded video, wait 10 seconds, then try again?

Has anyone else encountered this issue, specifically with batch/automatic uploading?  Thank you for any assistance.[This shows the uploaded and failed videos (titles removed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBQjM.png)

Comment: We have determined that this is most likely an internal error caused by missing video properties prior to reaching our internal deployment folder.  Due to the lack of video properties, the video is technically incomplete.  The java process currently cannot decipher between the two instances.  Current course of action is mitigating the internal error for missing properties.  I no longer consider this an open issue, but I am unaware how to close this.  Thanks.

Comment: have you solved this issue

Comment: @MrE have you solved this issue? I am having the same problem